# How to get the return value of a JavaScript function to a Python Variable

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to web scrape some information from a website local storage using selenium webdriver. I am using python 3.8.5 I want to return that JavaScript's output value to a python variable.

```
number = driver.execute_script("setTimeout(function(){ localStorage.getItem('value'); }, 1500);")
```

But when I print the variable **`number`** the result is None for some reason. Any ideas on what I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will navigate to this page where you asked this question and return the localStorage item "se:fkey" using javascript:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\\Path\\To\\Your\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63283026/how-to-get-the-return-value-of-a-javascript-function-to-a-python-variable')

a_returned = driver.execute_script("""
a_function = function(){
console.log(localStorage.getItem("se:fkey"));
return localStorage.getItem("se:fkey");
};
return a_function();

""")

print("a_returned:", a_returned)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to return from the JS script:

```py
print(driver.execute_script('return localStorage.getItem("value");'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass any value from client-side (javascript) to backend (python) you can use ajax for data sending here: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp

But the best way is to fetch the required data directly through python that would be fast enough. There are many packages/libraries like selenium, requests, beautiful soap with them you can do that.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this:

```
number = driver.execute_script("setTimeout(function(){ return localStorage.getItem('value'); }, 1500);")
```

Comment: a verbal explanation is often helpful